# Collapse Python list, keeping unique columns and highest value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, pandas

I have a list of lists

```
data = [ ['fruit', 'apple', 'v1', 'data 1'],
         ['fruit', 'apple', 'v2', 'data 2'],
         ['fruit', 'apple', 'v3', 'data 3'],
         ['fruit', 'banana', 'v1', 'data 4'],
         ['fruit', 'banana', 'v2', 'data 5'],
         ['animal', 'dog', 'v1', 'data 6'] ]
```

How can I collapse based on the first 2 column and using the data from the highest v ?

```
result = [ ['fruit', 'apple', 'v3', 'data 3'],
           ['fruit', 'banana', 'v2', 'data 5'],
           ['animal', 'dog', 'v1', 'data 6'] ]
```

The list was sorted in the first column, but second column is not. My solution was based on assumption that both column were sorted so it does not work and I have no idea where to go from here.

```
previous = []
result = []
for a, b, c, d in data:
    if not all(x in previous for x in [a, b]):
        final.append([a, b, c, d])
        previous = [a, b, c, d]
    else:
        if previous[2] < c:
            final[-1][2] = c
            final[-1][3] = d
            previous = [a, b, c, d]
print result
```

Comment: Is the list sorted? Also, what have you tried? Please show your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: The list was sorted on column 0, but column 1 is not. At first I thought both would be sorted so I came up with this solution. Editing it in.

Comment: Now that the second column is not sorted, I really have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ ['fruit', 'apple', 'v1', 'data 1'],
         ['fruit', 'apple', 'v2', 'data 2'],
         ['fruit', 'apple', 'v3', 'data 3'],
         ['fruit', 'banana', 'v1', 'data 4'],
         ['fruit', 'banana', 'v2', 'data 5'],
         ['animal', 'dog', 'v1', 'data 6'] ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'])
df['Grouper'] = df['Col1'] + df['Col2']
df['Order'] = df['Col3'].map(lambda x: int(x[-1]))

df = df.sort_values(['Grouper', 'Order'], ascending=[True, False])\
       .drop_duplicates('Grouper')\
       .drop(['Grouper', 'Order'], 1)

lst = df.values.tolist()

# [['animal', 'dog', 'v1', 'data 6'],
#  ['fruit', 'apple', 'v3', 'data 3'],
#  ['fruit', 'banana', 'v2', 'data 5']]
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that data in col2 repeats with different col1 too, and your code works perfect still.

May I ask what lambda x: int(x[-1]) do?

Comment: `lambda` is an anonymous function. This one takes a value, gets the last character of the string, then converts it to an integer.

Answer (score 4):

- You could use:

  - [[Python]: itertools.**groupby**(*iterable, key=None*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) - to group (outer) list elements based on their 1<sup>st</sup> 2 values (e.g. `("fruit", "banana")`)
  - [[Python]: **max**(*iterable, *[, key, default]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) - to get the maximum value of one such group, based on their 3<sup>rd</sup> element (the 1<sup>st</sup> letter("v") + the number that comes after it (fixed it, to work with numbers with more than one digit))
  - [[Python]: Lambda Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) - to specify the grouping criteria

  > ```
  > >>> import itertools
  > >>>
  > >>> data = [['fruit', 'apple', 'v1', 'some data'],
  > ...          ['fruit', 'apple', 'v2', 'some data'],
  > ...          ['fruit', 'apple', 'v3', 'some data'],
  > ...          ['fruit', 'banana', 'v1', 'some data'],
  > ...          ['fruit', 'banana', 'v2', 'some data'],
  > ...          ['animal', 'dog', 'v1', 'some data']]
  > >>>
  > >>> [max(item[1], key=lambda x: (x[2][0], int(x[2][1:]))) for item in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))]
  > [['fruit', 'apple', 'v3', 'some data'], ['fruit', 'banana', 'v2', 'some data'], ['animal', 'dog', 'v1', 'some data']]
  > ```
- Or you could go the (old fashioned) manual way (e.g. using a helper dictionary):

  > ```
  > >>> helper_dict = dict()
  > >>> for item in data:
  > ...    item_v = helper_dict.get((item[0], item[1]), (None, None, "v0"))[2]
  > ...    if (item_v[0], int(item_v[1:])) < (item[2][0], int(item[2][1:])):
  > ...             helper_dict[(item[0], item[1])] = item
  > ...
  > >>> print(list(helper_dict.values()))
  > [['fruit', 'apple', 'v3', 'some data'], ['animal', 'dog', 'v1', 'some data'], ['fruit', 'banana', 'v2', 'some data']]
  > ```

Answer (score 2):

**Another possible approach:**

(1) Create a dictionary which maps indices of the first and second columns, and maps the most recent index for each pair. This allows the data to be correctly sorted at the end.

(2) Create a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of all the different groupings of the first and second columns.

(3) Find each of the groupings maximum v value from (2) and combine it with the rest of the elements. This gets returned as the collapsed list.

(4) Sort the collapsed lists based on (1).

**Example code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['fruit', 'apple', 'v1', 'data 1'],
        ['fruit', 'apple', 'v2', 'data 2'],
        ['fruit', 'apple', 'v3', 'data 3'],
        ['fruit', 'banana', 'v1', 'data 4'],
        ['fruit', 'banana', 'v2', 'data 5'],
        ['animal', 'dog', 'v1', 'data 6']]

groups = defaultdict(list)
sort_map = {}
for i, (fst, snd, *rest) in enumerate(data):
    sort_map[(fst, snd)] = i
    groups[(fst, snd)].append(rest)

result = sorted((list(k) + max(v) for k, v in groups.items()), 
                                      key=lambda x: sort_map[(x[0], x[1])])

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['fruit', 'apple', 'v3', 'data 3'], 
 ['fruit', 'banana', 'v2', 'data 5'], 
 ['animal', 'dog', 'v1', 'data 6']]
```